# load SQL statements from a file using clojure.java.jdbc

Tags: jdbc, clojure

The REST call is sending the branchId and emplId to this exec-sql-file method. I am passing these as a parameter. I am not able to execute the SQL statement when I pass branch_id = @branchid and empl_id = @emplid. But when I hardcode the branch_id = 'BR101' and empl_id = 123456 then it is working. Any suggestion how to get the branch_Id and empl_Id in my some-statements.sql?

```
(defn exec-sql-file
  [branchid emplid]
  (sql/with-db-connection (db-conn)
    (sql/db-do-prepared conn
      [branchid emplid (slurp (resource "sql/some-statements.sql"))])))
```

some-statements.sql have this query

```
DELETE from customer where branch_id = @branchid and empl_id = @emplid;
```

I am executing this from REPL as

```
(exec-sql-file "BR101" 123456)
```

I grab the code snippet from the below post.

[Is it possible to patch load SQL statements from a file using clojure.java.jdbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120287/is-it-possible-to-patch-load-sql-statements-from-a-file-using-clojure-java-jdbc/37013250#37013250)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this as your approach requires that you have to provide parameters to multiple SQL statements in one run. Another issue is that Java's `PreparedStatement` (used under the hood by `clojure.java.jdbc`) doesn't support named parameters, so even if parameters to multiple SQL statements done using a single prepared statement would have to be provided for every placeholder (`?`).

I would suggest following solutions:

- use multiple prepared statements (so separate `clojure.java.jdbc/execute!` calls) for each of the SQL statement you want to execute wrapped in a single transaction (each SQL could be read from a separate file). You could also use some helper library like [YeSQL](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql) to make loading your SQL statements from external files and exposing them as functions you could call as ordinary Clojure functions. It would be simple but if you change the number of statements you would like to execute, then you need to change your code
- create a stored procedure and call them from Clojure providing the parameters - this will define an interface for some DB logic which will be defined on the DB side. Unless you change the interface of your stored procedure you can modify its implementation without changing your Clojure code or redeployment
- implement your own logic of interpolating named parameters into your "multistatement" SQL file. The issue is to appropriately escape parameters' values so your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection. I would discourage this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Piotrek. The some-statements.sql file also have Update, Insert functionalities and the where clause is branchid and emplid for all sql statement.

Comment: @Aiswa, it wasn't obvious to me from the question. I have updated my answer to reflect this requirement.

Comment: I tried this in other way. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.